# Xcode validate failed 'a sealed resource is missing or invalid'

Tags: ios, xcode

Yesterday I received an Email from Apple, Apple suggest developers validate their Xcode version, here is the link: [Validating your Xcode](https://developer.apple.com/news/?id=09222015a).

Check your Xcode version:

```
spctl --assess --verbose /Applications/Xcode.app
```

Normally we should see

```
/Applications/Xcode.app: accepted
source=Mac App Store

/Applications/Xcode.app: accepted
source=Apple
```

or

```
/Applications/Xcode.app: accepted
source=Apple System
```

But my Xcode downloaded from App Store said:

```
/Applications/Xcode.app: a sealed resource is missing or invalid
```

[image]

Comment: May be its depending upon the Gatekeeper settings. Please change the gatekeeper settings to 'Allow From Anywhere' and check result again.

Comment: Thank you sir @TusharJ. , you are right. When I changed it to 'Allow From Anywhere', the result changed to /Applications/Xcode.app: accepted
override=security disabled

Comment: Did you have previous SDK versions in your XCode app?  If so, that is causing your validation to fail. I also recommend reverting your change to the Gatekeeper settings to not Allow From Anywhere.  

http://stackoverflow.com/a/32832271/1286413

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest just downloading Xcode from the Mac App Store again, it should fix it.